# Android JUnit test for ArrayAdapter throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, junit4

I am trying to test the ArrayAdapter for my project but it keep returning null. I am not sure as to whether the there is a problem in the mockup with Mokito but the ArrayList with mocked data is being passed to the ArrayAdapter. Attached is the code with the test, could someone reproduce the error and let me know if there is a solution to passing data into the ArrayAdapter in the JUnit test?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class QuickUnitTest extends AndroidTestCase
{

   private static ReadResultActivity activity;

   private static String TAG = "TAG";

   @Mock
   static Context mContext;

   private static CustomerAdapter customerTest;
   private static CustomerType mJohn = new CustomerType();
   private static CustomerType mJane = new CustomerType();

    public QuickUnitTest()
    {

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp()throws Exception
    {
        activity = mock(ReadResultActivity.class);

        ArrayList <CustomerType> data = new ArrayList<>();

        mJohn.setCustID(1);
        mJohn.setFirstName("John");
        mJohn.setLastName("Doe");
        mJohn.setGpsCoords("blah");

        mJane.setCustID(2);
        mJane.setFirstName("Jane");
        mJane.setLastName("Doe");
        mJane.setGpsCoords("");


        data.add(mJohn);
        data.add(mJane);
        Log.e(TAG,data.get(0).getFirstName());

        customerTest = new CustomerAdapter(getContext(), data); // error here? 
        //not passing arraylist
        //Log.d("customerTest",customerTest.getItem(0).getFirstName());

     }

     @Test
     public void testGetItem()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, mJohn.getFirstName());

        Log.e(TAG, customerTest.getItem(0).getFirstName());

        assertEquals("John is expected.", mJohn.getFirstName(),     customerTest.getItem(0).getFirstName());



    }

    @Test
    public void testGetItemId()
    {
        assertEquals("Wrong ID.", 0, customerTest.getItemId(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCount()
    {
        assertEquals("Contacts amount incorrect.", 2, customerTest.getCount());
    }


}
```

Edit: Here is the backtraces as requested

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Contacts amount incorrect. 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
<Click to see difference>


at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:329)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:78)
at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:234)
at junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals(TestCase.java:401)
at com.mylayouts.nk.assessment2_webservice.QuickUnitTest.testGetCount(QuickUnitTest.java:95)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mylayouts.nk.webservice.QuickUnitTest.testGetItem(QuickUnitTest.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Are you testing the Arraylist, the POJO or the Adapter?

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: I am testing the the adapter, mocking the pojo and arraylist.

Comment: criket_007 do you want me to post the pojo and main source code?

Comment: Try  Context context = Mockito.mock(ReadResultActivity.class); and in getContext() use context

Comment: mubeen tried your suggestion... still the same